# Meaning of comment "Game. Set. Match."

Tags: meaning

What's the meaning of p2's comment?

> P1: My gf is a doctor and she makes twice as much as I do. F-k I feel like a weird mother f-ker. She makes all the bling at home. I only make around 42k a year as a fund accountant :(. Although she owes a sh-t ton in loans and I'm debt free.
>
> P2: "I'm debt free."
>   Game. Set. Match.

Comment: Careful with the LMGTFY comments and closing as gen ref: the meaning of this phrase is different than the sum of the meanings of the words, so you can't really look this up in a plain old dictionary. If you don't know that the origin is tennis, then you don't know that you're maybe supposed to look in sports reference book of some sort. And Google will happily return utter balderdash, so it is **[not general reference](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2374/google-is-not-general-reference)**.

Comment: @Marthaª [game, set and match](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/game?q=game+set+match#game__29) as they say.

Comment: @MattЭллен: that's a better dictionary than most, it appears. OneLook dictionary search only finds this phrase in the Urban Dictionary, which doesn't really count; and in a sports glossary, which only gives the literal tennis definition.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The phrase comes [from tennis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennis#Scoring):

> In tournament play, the chair umpire announces the end of the match with the well-known phrase "**Game, set, match**" followed by the winning person's or team's name.

It is similarly used in other contexts to indicate the winner, often in an argument or a comparison (as is the case here).

Answer (score 7):

It's a reference to a sport (most notably, tennis) that is broken down into matches, which are won by a number of sets, which are composed of games. Saying "game, set, match" is a short way of declaring that you won and/or are the ultimate winner. I.e. "I won the game, which means I won the set, which means I won the match". In this instance, they are using it figuratively to declare that the fact that the first commenter is debt free, is greater than (and trumps) the fact that his girlfriend makes more money than him.

Answer (score -6):

A phrase used by someone that knows they just got their ass handed to them in an argument.

Comment: That clearly isn't the meaning here.